# Is it possible to support oneself as a lifelong graduate student?

Tags: phd, masters, funding, academic-life

I don't care much for being rich. I don't mind a modest life if I can just do research in the field I love.

Thus I am curious to know if it is possible to make a living just by studying. (Suppose I could hypothetically get funding for every Master or PhD program). Is there an age limit or a limit to the number of PhD degrees that I could get? Are there any other reasons that prevent this?

Comment: if you "hypothetically" could get funding, yes. but that is a huge if, a completely unrealistic hypothesis.

Comment: I wonder if you make the same mistake I made when I was young, I thought that studying and doing research was the same thing. You can make a living doing research, studying not so much.

Comment: @henning Even with funding, a university is fairly unlikely to admit somebody to study a second PhD and it would be hard to find an advisor. For a *third* PhD, it would be virtually impossible.

Comment: Or you can live on welfare...on a recent trip to the UK it also appears that it is effectively possible to go to school constantly and live off of government loans without needing to ever repay them, and with forgiveness after 10 years.  Just talking to a few family members who'd been through the UK system, I wasn't able to find out how this loophole was closed.  Perhaps there is a class of perpetual students in the UK.

Comment: Step 1: realize that collecting PhDs is a fairly useless endeavour. Having 1 proves you can do research, having multiple proves little more. After obtaining a PhD in a field you like you would have to move to another one to get another PhD (or, you know, do what most people do and start a postdoc in the field you like).

Comment: In short, no - at some point you're going to actually have to get a job. Sad but true - the academic party bus eventually grinds to a stop. You can drag it out as long as you possibly can, if that's what you think you want, but perhaps you need to step back and ask yourself why this seems like an attractive option. Are you unduly concerned about going out into "the real world"? A lack of interest in/fear of change? Happy with what's familiar/don't want to do anything different? Perhaps talking it over with a counselor could provide some valuable insights.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, Why is it hard to get a second PhD? Aren't there university courses for adults? And aren't there also many people who switch fields?

Comment: @yters Do you have any evidence that it's possible to get loans for second and subsequent bachelor's degrees in the UK? I've never heard of such a thing happening.

Comment: @Pacerier A PhD *is* a university course for adults! A second PhD has very little value and is absolutely not required to change fields. PhDs consume significant resources: most universities and academics would rather use those resources to get somebody a first PhD, not to get somebody a second PhD that they don't need.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, not quite sure how it works, but my understanding is an acquaintance is working on her second degree in midwifery using government loans, after already getting a first degree in linguistics.

Comment: @yters It's possible that the distinction there is that a degree in midwifery is training for a specific occupation in a way that a degree in, say, mathematics or philosophy isn't.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, Oops, "adult" is the wrong word... What I meant is, aren't there PhD courses for "older people"? E.g. someone who retired at 35 and then started pursuing a PhD after retirement. Or someone who decided after 5 years that his current PhD subject is not something he want to do for his life and then switch.

Comment: @Pacerier The early retirement case sounds like somebody doing their first PhD. Nothing I said was about age: it was about getting multiple PhDs. Somebody who decides 5 years into their PhD that they don't like it should probably either buckle down and finish it or try to adapt the project to something they're more interested in. But, again, if they quit that PhD and start a second, that's not a case of somebody getting multiple PhDs. (Though I imagine most sources of funding would be very wary of somebody who'd quit one PhD asking for money to start another.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby, Ic. So the only people with multiple Phds are those that come from uber rich families (since they can simply pay themselves)?

Comment: @Pacerier People just don't do multiple PhDs. It's not how the system works. As I said, a PhD student requires a large commitment of resources from the university. Universities and, in particular, advisors don't commit those resources just so that people can collect PhDs as a hobby.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Why would you want to get multiple PhD degrees when the first one is all you need to do research for life? Much of the point of the degree is a certification of your ability to do independent research. After you've done that, you can get a job where you do research all day long! Many people get a professor's job where there are other duties, but plenty of people get jobs doing just research at government labs or non-teaching academic departments (like me!).

Comment: I didn't know that, and this is maybe what I was looking for! thanks (Is not so clear to me in how scientists manage to keep doing researches after they get their a-kind-of-degree and I thought they just do many PhDs)

Comment: No, not at all. We write grant proposals to government agencies which fund research like [NSF](http://www.nsf.gov/) and [NIH](http://www.nih.gov/). We use that money to pay salaries of researchers to do the proposed projects.

Comment: _when the first one is all you need to do research for life?_ — In fact, you don't even need the first one.

Comment: @JeffE, yeah, but it increases the odds in most fields somewhat.

Comment: @JeffE Same as how one doesn't strictly need a college degree to get a job, but in some fields it increases the odds considerably.

Comment: @Bill Barth If you don't mind me asking, what field is your PhD in and what kind of research are you doing right now? People always say it is not worth doing PhD unless you want to stay at university.

Comment: @N0ir, I finished my PhD in Aerospace Engineering at UT Austin in 2004. I work for [TACC](http://www.tacc.utexas.edu/) also at UT. I have a managerial and research role leading a group of ~20 PhDs supporting our HPC user community and doing research. Clearly many jobs in the US have a PhD as a requirement and aren't in academia: pharma industry research, national labs, computer industry research, etc.

Comment: @BillBarth, You might be able to find a job that allows you to do research that you like, but the real problem is not everyone is as lucky to live in the U.S. where the government pays for research.

Comment: @Pacerier, yes, sure, but many people who will read this do live in the US, EU, Japan, and other regions or countries with governments that do pay for research. The question is not "can everyone" or even "can I" but "if it is possible" to do so. And the answer to that question is clearly "Yes!" In addition, many of my staff are international folks who have competed against strong pools of candidates to join our team from abroad, so it is also possible to move internationally to pursue a research lifestyle. If you are good at research and willing to move, there are lots of opportunities.

Answer (score 16):

Another point is that many PhD programs (in the U.S., for sure) will not admit people who already have a PhD, no matter that it was/is in a different topic, etc., with or without funding.

And, these days, in the U.S., funding for graduate study in many subjects is shrinking, for many reasons. While it is illegal to discriminate based on age in the U.S., I think most PhD programs gauge their own success significantly by how well their graduates do in the academic (or other) professional spheres, and effectively promising to not participate would most likely kill chances of funding... Certainly does not help.

That is, in general consonance with the other answers, getting a PhD is just an initial step toward being an independent scholar (if not necessarily a commodified "researcher" in the grant-getting sense, etc). These programs are aimed at people who are intellectually/technically slightly immature (whatever their chronological age), and who do some sort of apprenticeship. If you think about it that way, an itinerant endless-apprentice is not what people want, because they want to have apprentices become "journeymen", in the archaic but useful sense.

Comment: independent scholar vs. commodified researcher -- that is an interesting distinction.

Comment: @henning, "Independent scholar"? Whatever is an "independent scholar" all about? What do they do?

Comment: @Pacerier, "independent" in the sense of not being an "intellectually dependent" student/apprentice to a more experienced person. No implication was intended about "financial independence".

Comment: @paulgarrett, Ic, so the distinction is not between "independent scholar" vs. "commodified researcher" because one could be both.

Comment: @Pacerier, yes, once could have become "independent" of  one's thesis advisor, and do genuine research, without necessarily having written grant proposals and gotten federal funding (thinking about the U.S.)

Comment: @paulgarrett, Actually most of these "independent scholars" are "commodified researchers". Just look at the number of Phds Google (and friends) are hiring these days.

Answer (score 14):

> Is there a limit of age in studing? Is there a limit of numbers of PhD that I could get?

No, but realistically there is a limit for how many years / PhDs you will find funding agencies and advisors who put up with you. Funding agencies / universities do not give out stipends just for fun - once it becomes obvious that you are really just studying everything without ever taking the next career step, nobody will be particularly thrilled to invest time, energy, and money into teaching you something that you actually don't plan to ever put to use.

Comment: I'm not saying that I'm not interested in use what I lear, or doing it just for fun, but more like improving my knodledge by working doing researches. I wouldn't like to study in some thesis that I know it will never be usefull. Thanks for the answer!, when you put like this, sounds more obvious, sorry, maybe my problem is thinking that just in school someone can improve his knodledge...